# How do I change a Class's attribute through lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, properties, attributes

```
class myobject:
    attrib = 0
```

I have this class and I put `myobject.attrib` into a list like this.
I try to change the mutable class through the list

```
thelist = [object(), myobject.attrib]

thelist[1] = 1
print(myobject.attrib)
```

And the problem is that `myobject.attrib` is still showing up as `0` instead of `1`.

I suspect that its basically changing index `1` of `thelist`. How do I change the attribute of the class within the list instead?

Comment: You can't. The list holds a reference to the same value the attribute does - changing what the list references doesn't impact the object _at all_. Recommended reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: If you do `thelist = [object(), myobject]` instead, then `thelist[1].attrib = 1` would work.

Comment: Make the attribute mutable: `class myobject: attrib = [0]`. Then you can do `thelist[1][0] = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class myobject:
    attrib = 0
    attrib_2 = 0
    

# The id() function returns a unique id for the specified object.The id is based on object's memory address.
print("Id of myobject.attrib : ",id(myobject.attrib))
print("Id of myobject : ",id(myobject))


# Passing myobject as third value.
thelist = [object(), myobject.attrib,  myobject]

print("Id of list[1] : ",id(thelist[1])) # => here it reffers to integer memory in myobject.attrib.
print("Id of list[2] : ",id(thelist[2])) # => here it reffers to memory of myobject 

thelist[1] = 1
print("Id after changing value attrib : ",id(thelist[1])) # => One's reassigned, Immutable object int memmory changes to a new location, which don't have any reference to myobject.

thelist[2].attrib_2 =1 #Change the value of attrib_2 in myobject as the thelist[2] referes to it's memory since it's mutable.
print("Id myobject after changing value myobject.attrib_2: ",id(thelist[2])) # => Id will be same as the memmory doesn't change. 

print("No change :", myobject.attrib)
print("Changed :", myobject.attrib_2)
```

> output

```
Id of myobject.attrib :  2278365358352
Id of myobject :  2278373329984
Id of list[1] :  2278365358352
Id of list[2] :  2278373329984
Id after changing value attrib :  2278365358384
Id myobject after changing value myobject.attrib_2:  2278373329984
No change : 0
Changed : 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyObject:
    attrib = 0

thelist = [MyObject(), MyObject.attrib]

MyObject.attrib = 1

print(MyObject.attrib)
```

this one work for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).